# Activator - how to recompile with -Xlint:unchecked?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I run my play application using the `run` command from inside `activator`. When I open the index page, after compiling the sources, the console prints

```
[warn] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[warn] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

How do I do that? How do I recompile with that parameter? I've tried running activator with `activator -J-Xlint:unchecked` and `JAVA_OPTS="-Xlint:unchecked" activator`, both of which resulted in

```
Unrecognized option: -Xlint:unchecked
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to your build.sbt:

```
javacOptions += "-Xlint:unchecked"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Is there a way of doing this via command-line arguments?

Comment: I don't think `sbt` or `activator` takes these cmd line switches into account - as I think you have discovered. I usually enable them in a development branch and then disable them when I push back to mainline.